# Warum wird "Neuestem" hier groß geschrieben?

Tags: adjective, noun, spelling, capitalization, nominalization

[ARD Tagesschau Aktuelle Nachrichtens Hauptseite](https://www.tagesschau.de/) meldet:

> Luftblasen wirbeln Müll auf, der dann abgefischt werden kann: Mit der Erfindung junger Tüftler werden seit Neuestem in Amsterdam Grachten gereinigt. Das Projekt könnte weltweit funktionieren. Gudrun Engel berichtet.

Warum wird *Neuestem* hier mit grossem "N" geschrieben?  Das ist hier wohl Superlativ Dativ des Adjektiv "neu"?  Ist es falsch?

Comment: Bemerkenswert ist hier, dass *seit Neuestem* erst seit neuestem großgeschrieben wird (oder werden kann).

Answer (score 6):

*Seit* ist eine Präposition. Das Adjektiv *neu* (mit der Superlativform *neueste*) wird hier ähnlich wie ein Substantiv gebraucht: Sein Kasus (Dativ) wird voll von der Präposition determiniert und es ist nicht bloß Bestandteil einer Nominalphrase mit einem anderen Kopf (wie etwa in *seit dem neuen Jahr*). Diesen Gebrauch bezeichnet man als substantivisch und *Neuestem* in Ihrem Beispiel entsprechend als Substantivierung.

[§ 57 des amtlichen Regelwerks:](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6194#par57)

> Wörter anderer Wortarten schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive
>   gebraucht werden (= Substantivierungen). (...)

[§ 58 des amtlichen Regelwerks:](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6194#par58)

> In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen
>   klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen.
>
> (...)
>
> (3) bestimmte feste Verbindungen
>
> (...)
>
> (3.2) aus Präposition und dekliniertem Adjektiv ohne vorangehenden
>   Artikel. In diesen Fällen ist jedoch auch die Großschreibung des
>   Adjektivs zulässig, zum Beispiel:
>   *Aus der Brandruine stieg von neuem/Neuem Rauch auf. Wir konnten das Feuer nur von weitem/Weitem betrachten. Der Fahrplan bleibt bis auf
>   weiteres/Weiteres in Kraft. Unsere Pressesprecherin gibt Ihnen ohne
>   weiteres/Weiteres Auskunft. Der Termin stand seit längerem/Längerem
>   fest. Die Aufgabe wird binnen kurzem/Kurzem erledigt.*

Wie aus § 58(3.2) hervorgeht, ist also auch die Schreibung *seit neuestem* zulässig.

Comment: Alte Schreibung (vor der sogenannten Rechtschreibreform) war stets klein: *seit neuem, seit kurzem, seit langem*... (Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch 2. Aufl. 1989, S. 1381.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann wieso *sogenannte* Rechtschreibreform? Der Begriff ist doch zutreffend, denn es handelte sich dabei um eine Reform (Veränderung) der Rechtschreibung (Orthographie). Keiner der beiden Bestandteile hat Anzweiflungs-Potenzial. Hättest Du in dem Zusammenhang von einer *sogenannten Verbesserung* geschrieben, dann wäre dies eine legitime (und im Sinne der Sprachlogik sinnvolle) Meinungsäußerung (der ich nicht zustimmen würde, aber das ist für diese Fragestellung irrelevant).

Comment: @Ja, aber dann kann ich auch fragen, warum Leute so reflexhaft von der "ehemaligen DDR" sprechen. Was soll das? Sagen wir auch "der ehemalige Kaiser Napoleon"?

Answer (score 2):

Die Frage lautet:

> Warum wird *Neuestem* hier mit großem N geschrieben?

Für die Antwort braucht man keine Tauchfahrten in die Tiefen der deutschen Schulgrammatik zu unternehmen. Die Antwort liegt nämlich recht offensichtlich an der Oberfläche:

> Weil das mit der "Rechtschreibreform" von 1996 so festgelegt bzw. nahegelegt wurde.

Davor schrieb man Ausdrücke wie *vor kurzem*, *seit langem*, *seit neuestem* immer stets ausschließlich und unverrückbar klein.<sup>1</sup>

Alles weitere Warumisieren über unterstellte grammatische Gründe ist eitle Sophisterei ex post. Was man dagegen tun kann, ist zu fragen:

> Warum haben die Rechtschreibreformer das so entschieden?

Die Antwort ist:

> Weil sie glaubten, dass die Bevölkerung, insbesondere ihr schulpflichtiger Teil, leichter damit zurechtkommt, wenn man alles, was ein bisschen wie ein Substantiv aussieht, groß schreibt.

Damit haben sie im allgemeinen (!) vielleicht recht (!). Im wesentlichen (!) war damit aber niemandem (!) wirklich geholfen.

---

<sup>1</sup> Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch 2. Aufl. 1989, S. 1381.